# Transform Entity with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Let's assume my example entity `TeamPlayer` looks like this:

```
PlayerId    PlayerName   Team       Position
----------------------------------------------
1           Nobody       Team A      Striker
1           Nobody       Team B      Center Midfield
1           Nobody       Team C      Substitute
2           Chuck Norris TeamA      ALL
2           Chuck Norris TeamB      Substitute
```

What i try to achieve is to write a C# method where i pass the player id. The result should be an XML string like this (if 1 is passed to the method):

```
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="urn:teamsoftware:playermanager:playerovierview">
    <player>
        <playerid>1</playerid>
        <playername>Nobody</playername>
        <team>TeamA
TeamB
TeamC</team>
        <position>Striker
Center Midfield
Substiture</position>
    </player>
</ns0:root>
```

So if a player joins more teams they should be inside `<team>`tag, seperated by CR LF. I know this is an ugly solution, but data are delivered to a third-party tool so they have to look like this unfortunately :/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you coded so far? on which part can we help?

Comment: So do you have some `List<TeamPlayer>` or similar to query this data from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly as that is, it doesn't sound too hard using `string.Join` to create the appropriate text contents. After fetching the relevant data - which I assume you know how to do - you could just use something like:

```
var records = ...; // The player records
XNamespace ns = "urn:teamsoftware:playermanager:playerovierview";
return new XElement(ns + "root",
    new XElement("player",
        new XElement("playerid", records.First().PlayerId),
        new XElement("playername", records.First().PlayerName),
        new XElement("team", string.Join("\r\n", records.Select(x => x.Team)),
        new XElement("position", string.Join("\r\n", records.Select(x => x.Position))
    )
);
```

Comment: If the sample XML is correct, then none of the children of `root` have namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but i get an error message like `'TeamPlayer' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'TeamPlayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  appears in the line where team names should be joined :/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("PlayerId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("PlayerName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Team", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Postition", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"Nobody", "Team A", "Striker"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"Nobody", "Team B", "Center Midfield"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1,"Nobody", "Team C", "Substitute"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2,"Chuck Norris", "Team A", "ALL"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {2,"Chuck Norris", "Team B", "Substitute"});

            DataTable results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>("PlayerId") == 1).ToList().CopyToDataTable();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(results);
            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

        }

    }
}
```